# AceEditor' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type 'typeof ReactAce' is not a valid JSX element type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this project that mostly uses jsx extensions despite being setup with typescript. When creating a new component, I decided to go with the tsx extension and ran into this error:

```
'AceEditor' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof ReactAce' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
      Type 'new (props: IAceEditorProps) => ReactAce' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.
        Construct signature return types 'ReactAce' and 'Component<any, any, any>' are incompatible.
          The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
            Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

I searched and found nothing and tried type assertion: as unknown as JSX.Element, but that didn't work either.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';

// Import necessary modes and themes from ace-builds
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-python';
// Add more modes here as needed

import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github'; // You can change the theme if you wish
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-monokai'; // You can change the theme if you wish

interface CodeEditorProps {
    language: string;
    starterCode: string;
    code: string;
    onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
    fontSize?: number; // Make fontSize an optional prop
}

const CodeEditorAce: React.FC<CodeEditorProps> = ({
    language,
    starterCode,
    code,
    onChange,
    fontSize = 14,
}) => {
    // Default fontSize is set to 14, but can be overridden by props

    const getMode = (language: string) => {
        switch (language.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'javascript':
                return 'javascript';
            case 'python':
                return 'python';
            // Add more cases for other languages you support
            default:
                return 'text';
        }
    };

    let value = code ? code : starterCode;

    return (
        <AceEditor
            placeholder="Do not edit the starter code."
            mode={getMode(language)}
            theme="monokai"
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            name={`code-editor-${Math.random()}`} // Ensures a unique ID
            editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
            showPrintMargin={true}
            showGutter={true}
            highlightActiveLine={true}
            setOptions={{
                enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
                enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
                enableSnippets: true,
                showLineNumbers: true,
                tabSize: 2,
            }}
            fontSize={fontSize} // Set the font size here
            height="100%"
            width="100%"
        />
    );
};

export default CodeEditorAce;
```

I also get the same issue if I use code mirror instead of Ace Editor:

```
'CodeMirror' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<ReactCodeMirrorProps & RefAttributes<ReactCodeMirrorRef>>' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<ReactCodeMirrorProps & RefAttributes<ReactCodeMirrorRef>>' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

```
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-ace": "^10.1.0",
        "ace-builds": "^1.32.7",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

I installed the types for ace and didn't do much either.